# Comparing mysql dates in php

Tags: php, mysql, date

I'm creating an application for a friend to handle Deadlines. I have a page set up where each user can see their own 'jobs to do' with a deadline next to it. My question is...

How do I compare a deadline date that comes back from the mysql query as 2010.08.08 with today's date?

For Example...

```
 <?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

$jobfinishdate = $row['jobfinishdate'];
$date = date('Y-m-d');

if ($jobfinishdate>$date)
 $jobfinishdate .= " - Not due yet!" ;
 else if ($jobfinishdate<$date)
  $jobfinishdate .= " - You didn't meet this deadline!";
  else if ($jobfinishdate==$date)
 $jobfinishdate .= " - Deadline is TODAY!";
```

}
    ?>

This works ok. But what I'd really like to do is display a message saying 'you have 5 days until deadline. Any ideas how to get around this?

Thanks.

Shane.

Comment: Is there a reason to compare the dates as strings? It looks strange to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible I would let the database return the number of days, with a query like this:

```
SELECT jobfinishdate, datediff(jobfinishdate, NOW() AS days) FROM table
```

Then use this number of days:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $jobfinishdate = $row['jobfinishdate'];
    $days = $row['days'];   

    if ($days > 0) {
        $jobfinishdate .= " - Not due yet! $days until deadline" ;
    } elseif ($days < 0) {
        $jobfinishdate .= " - You didn't meet this deadline!";
    } else {
        $jobfinishdate .= " - Deadline is TODAY!";
}
```

}

Some other remarks:

- If you keep the date calculation in PHP, move the $date declaration outside the while loop because you only need to do that once.
- you can remove the last condition, if ($jobfinishdate==$date). If the date is not larger and not smaller, it can only be equal.

Comment: Thanks. This way very helpful. Your idea on the database query was exactly what I was 'looking' for, it seems much more logical this way. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$days = (strtotime($jobfinishdate) - strtotime($date)) / (60 * 60 * 24);
```

Should get you the amount of days left on the deadline.

Edit: The above will always return the difference in days - to handle whether or not its before or beyond the due date, maybe (using just `time()` as Adam suggested):

```
$date_passed = false;
$days = strtotime($jobfinishdate) - time();
if ($days < 0) { $date_passed = true; }
$days = $days / (60 * 60 * 24);

if (!$date_passed)
{
  echo "You have $days days left on this project.";
}
else
{
  echo "Deadline has expired $days days ago.";
}
```

Comment: And you can skip a step: `(strtotime($jobfinishdate) - time())/(60*60*24)`

Comment: Spot on! Works a treat, thanks a bunch. Just another quick one. Would you class this as a long way round (even though it works) ? Would there be a more logical way of doing this, possibly changing date formats or something? Cheers for your help.

Comment: That's the nail in the coffin guys. Thanks alot, it works perfectly!

Comment: Yeah, you could have your mysql query return both the 'jobfinishdate' and the difference in days between that date and `NOW()`, handling that aspect of the logic in mysql.

Comment: I set up a timesheet application where I store dates as strings '08/09/2010'.  I've regretted it ever since.  If I had to do it again, I'd store the date as a unix timestamp.  If find them easier to work with, set up comparisons, and calculate days with.

Answer (score 2):

```
// calculate days left
$daysleft = round( ( strtotime( $jobfinishdate ) - time() ) / 86400 );

// print out text for $daysleft
if( $daysleft == 0 )
   print( "Deadline is today!" );
else if ( $daysleft > 0 )
   printf( "You have %d days until deadline.", $daysleft );
else
   print( "You did not meet the deadline!" );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP 5.3.0 or newer you can use the [DateTime object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Answer (score 0):

In SQL query:

```
SELECT
...,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, NOW(), `date_deadline`) AS days_to_deadline
...
```

This will produce positive number of days due deadline and negative for expired tasks.

Comment: Would I simply tag this onto the end of my Query then ?

$query = "SELECT * FROM $var WHERE jobstatus='0' ORDER BY jobfinishdate ASC TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, NOW(), `date_deadline`) AS days_to_deadline";

?

Comment: this should be added before `FROM` -> `SELECT *, TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, NOW(), date_deadline) AS days_to_deadline FROM $var ...`. And don't forget to change column name `date_deadline` to your column holding deadline date.